# Does DISTINCT performs a full table scan with multiple expressions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DISTINCT clause to remove the duplicate values.
What is the performance if there are multiple expressions?
For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, state
FROM customers
WHERE total_orders > 10
ORDER BY city;
```

Will this perform a full table scan?

Comment: Without knowing what indexes are on the table.... who knows?

Comment: I didn't specify.
There is no indexing. (Just for the Id in customers)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Oracle's programming language PL/SQL. I'll remove that tag.

Comment: If there is no indexing then all it can do is a table scan. There are no other intermediate data structures to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBMS performs a full table scan when it thinks it appropriate.

In your example, when the DBMS thinks that with `total_orders > 10` it will only get very few rows and there is an index on that column, it will use that index to access the table records. In a second step it will apply `DISTINCT` and then sort (or sort on-the-fly when making rows distinct). If the DBMS thinks however it will get too many records with `total_orders > 10` it may decide for a full table scan. (And then apply `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`). So whatever the situation, `DISTINCT` doesn't change anything.

In case you have an index on `total_orders` + `City` + `state`, the DBMS may decide not to access the table at all, because all data exists in the index and even in the order needed. The DBMS would do the same without `DISTINCT`, however.

In case you have an index on `state` + `total_orders` + `City` (i.e. wrong order; the `WHERE` clause can not be directly applied), the DBMS may still decide to read the index only, but it is less likely. And again: the DBMS would do the same without `DISTINCT`.

And if you have no index, the DBMS must do a full table scan of course, because there is no index to circumvent it. Well, I guess that was needless to say :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Will this perform a full table scan?

Check the **EXPLAIN PLAN**.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

It is up to the **optimizer** to decide the optimal plan for execution of the query. Since you do not have an **index** on the column used in the **filter predicate**, it has no other option than a **FTS**(**F**ull **T**able **S**can).